# Claue theme and image positioning in Google

Tags: magento2.2

A few months ago we migrated from 1.9.2 to Magento 2.2.4 and also changed the template, using Claue. Before we had an average of 120 clicks a day in the images positioned in Google and now 20 on average. The developers of Claue have modified several times code but still do not come up with the problem of positioning my images since they remain the same.
I show you how was the average position a year ago when I was in Magento 1.9 with another template and how it is now with Claue.

I thought the problem could be using Lazy Load with the images and I stopped using it three weeks ago but the behavior is the same.
The store is www.shopmami.com. Someone could help me?
[image]